# Complex expressions in python reduce

Tags: python, lambda

Is there a smart way to sum a list, but actually perform a map type function prior to summing.

I'm trying to combine these functions into one function that uses the lambda:

```
xlist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum(map(lambda x: (x - 1.0)**2, xlist))

# result = 14.0
```

I'm trying this:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + (y - 1.0)**2, xlist)

# result = 15.0
```

But it is not the same result. What is the smartest way to solve this. I'm kind of curious, I know I can use `sum(map())` but I wonder if reduce can be used in this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yea, you just need to pass an initial value of `0`:

```
>>> xlist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + (y - 1.0)**2, xlist, 0)
14.0
>>>
```

Keep in mind though that `reduce` is generally hated by Python programmers because of how unreadable it is.  You would probably be better off using the first approach.

Or, even better, use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
sum((x - 1.0)**2 for x in xlist)
```

This is a lot easier to read and is also more efficient because `map` creates an unnecessary list.

Comment: first method is also faster on my machine

Comment: That is probably because the list is small.  I'm sure it will change with a larger input.  Besides, it doesn't change the fact that `map` builds a list which we just throw away.  The genexp is also more readable (well, at least IMO).

Comment: faster on a list of 10000 elements, just using sum is the fastest of all